# JQuery mobile multiselect option limit

Tags: jquery

As this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524280/how-can-i-limit-selecting-options-in-multi-select-popup-of-jquery-mobile)

i try to limit selecting options in multi select popup of jQuery mobile

It did not work with me also i want limited the selected option to 3.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply edit the code to this:

```
    $(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $("#select").on("change", function () {
        var selected = $("option:selected", this).length;
        if (selected == 3) {
            $("option:not(:selected)", this).prop("disabled", true);
            $(this).selectmenu("refresh");
        }
        if (selected < 3) {
            $("option:disabled", this).prop("disabled", false);
            $(this).selectmenu("refresh");
        }
    });
});
```

We Reduced         `if (selected == 3) {` to 3.

Working [JSfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zh76d8c0/5/)

Comment: Thanks very much
I use menu like this :http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/
Where do I put code did not work because the page menu appears in popup

Comment: Glad I could help, would appreciate if you mark the answered checkmark :)

Comment: Is this code work with version jquery.mobile-1.4.0 , I tried but not work with me.
I want to work on this version because navbar icons not work on this version.

Comment: If you are using a long listbox selectbox, change the refresh to  $( this ).selectmenu("refresh", true);